# What is the proper way of modifying a value of an entry in a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am a beginner in Rust, I haven't finished the "Book" yet, but one thing made me ask this question.

Considering this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut entries = HashMap::new();
    entries.insert("First".to_string(), 10);
    entries.entry("Second".to_string()).or_insert(20);

    assert_eq!(10, *entries.get("First").unwrap());

    entries.entry(String::from("First")).and_modify(|value| { *value = 20});

    assert_eq!(20, *entries.get("First").unwrap());

    entries.insert("First".to_string(), 30);

    assert_eq!(30, *entries.get("First").unwrap());

}
```

I have used two ways of modifying an entry:

```
entries.entry(String::from("First")).and_modify(|value| { *value = 20});
entries.insert("First".to_string(), 30);
```

The `insert` way looks clunkish, and I woundn't personally use it to modify a value in an entry, but... it works. Nevertheless, is there a reason not to use it other than semantics? As I said, I'd rather use the `entry` construct than just bruteforcing an update using `insert` with an existing key. Something a newbie Rustacean like me could not possibly know?

Comment: Did you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#updating-a-hash-map yet?

Comment: I was at "Accessing Values in a Hash Map", silly me. The section on updating a HashMap was a few pixels away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert()` is a bit more idiomatic when you are replacing an entire value, particularly when you don't know (or care) if the value was present to begin with.

`get_mut()` is more idiomatic when you want to do something to a value that requires mutability, such as replacing only one field of a struct or invoking a method that requires a mutable reference.  If you know the key is present you can use `.unwrap()`, otherwise you can use one of the other `Option` utilities or `match`.

`entry(...).and_modify(...)` *by itself* is rarely idiomatic; it's more useful when chaining other methods of `Entry` together, such as where you want to modify a value if it exists, otherwise add a different value.  You might see this pattern when working with maps where the values are totals:

```
entries.entry(key)
    .and_modify(|v| *v += 1)
    .or_insert(1);
```